# How can I force a git rebase and override merge conflicts

Tags: git, version-control

I have a local and remote dev branch which is good. My master branch, however, is having some issues. The dev branch is solid enough that I can rebase master from dev.

When I run `git rebase dev` from my checked out master branch, it shows 1k+ conflicts. Way too many to go through one by one.

How can I rebase or reset the master branch so it is completely replaced by my dev branch? I know this isn't the right command but is there something like a `git rebase dev --force` or `git reset --hard origin/dev` or something I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally never rebase master on top of another branch (which was most likely created from master)

> so it is *completely* replaced by my `dev` branch?

The `git reset --hard origin/dev` should be enough (assuming you are on `master`), followed by a git push --force, provided you clearly communicate to any user of that repo they need to reset they own local master to the new history.

Make sure you don't have any pending modification.